# SwiftUI: Custom label in navigation link is greyed out

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, lazyvgrid

I'm trying to use my custom card view as label to navigation link. this navigation link is also a Grid item.
The result is a[image]

My Card Code:

```
struct CityCard: View {
    var cityData: CityData
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(cityData.name)")
                .padding([.top], 10)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: cityData.forecastIcon)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
            Spacer()
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Text(String(format: "%.2f $", cityData.rate))
                    .padding([.leading, .bottom], 10)
                Spacer()
                Text(String(format: "%.2f °", cityData.degrees))
                    .padding([.trailing, .bottom], 10)
            }
        }.frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .navigationTitle(cityData.name)
    }
}
```

My List View:

```
struct CityList: View {
    var cities: [CityData]
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 150, maximum: 150)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 150, maximum: 150))
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(self.cities) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.name), label: {
                        CityCard(cityData: item)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

someone has a solution why it gives me this opacity?

Update:
The main contact view is:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's greyed out because you don't yet have a `NavigationView` in your view hierarchy, which makes it possible to actually navigate to a new view.

You can, for example, wrap your `ScrollView` in a `NavigationView`:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(self.cities) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.name), label: {
                        CityCard(cityData: item)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if it's only happening in your preview, add a `NavigationView` to your preview code:

```
NavigationView {
  CityList(...)
}
```

Keep in mind that if you have the default accent color (blue, in light mode) that your links will become invisible (since they will be blue) on top of the blue background. You can set a custom accent color in your project or via the `accentColor` modifier:

```
NavigationView {
    //content
}.accentColor(.black)
```

Comment: I updated my question below, I wrapped it in navigation view

Comment: Please see the part of my answer where I address this -- see the paragraph starting with "Keep in mind that if you have the default accent color"

Comment: Thank you very much!!